# How to write Python code for salary rules in odoo payroll module?

Tags: python, odoo, software-design, odoo-16

I set payroll rule in Odoo, but is giving an error saying the python code is wrong, but it doesn't show me where is wrong.
Here is my code, and I am using Odoo variables:
Available variables:

payslip: object containing the payslips

employee: hr.employee object

contract: hr.contract object

rules: object containing the rules code (previously computed)

categories: object containing the computed salary rule categories (sum of amount of all rules belonging to that category).

worked_days: object containing the computed worked days.

object containing the computed inputs.

Note: returned value have to be set in the variable 'result'

```
def calcular_imposto_renda(salario_bruto, tabela):
  """Calculates the income tax for the given salary.

  Args:
    salario_bruto: The employee's monthly gross salary.
    tabela: The table of income tax intervals and corresponding values.

  Returns:
    The amount of income tax to be deducted.
  """

  # Find the appropriate income tax interval.
  for intervalo in tabela:
    if limite_inferior <= salario_bruto <= limite_superior:
      break

  # Calculate the income tax.
  if intervalo['limite_superior'] is None:
    # O limite superior é infinito, então o imposto é calculado sobre todo o salário.
    valor_base = salario_bruto
  else:
    # O limite superior é finito, então o imposto é calculado sobre a diferença entre o salário e o limite inferior.
    valor_base = salario_bruto - limite_inferior

  imposto = valor_base * intervalo['coeficiente']

  return imposto

# Definir tabela de intervalos e valores correspondentes
tabela_imposto = [
  {'limite_inferior': 0.00, 'limite_superior': 20.249.99, 'coeficiente': 0.0},
  {'limite_inferior': 20.250.00, 'limite_superior': 20.749.99, 'coeficiente': 0.10},
  {'limite_inferior': 20.750.00, 'limite_superior': 20.999.99, 'coeficiente': 0.10},
  {'limite_inferior': 21.000.00, 'limite_superior': 21.249.99, 'coeficiente': 0.10},
  {'limite_inferior': 21.250.00, 'limite_superior': 21.749.99, 'coeficiente': 0.10},
  {'limite_inferior': 21.750.00, 'limite_superior': 22.249.99, 'coeficiente': 0.10},
  {'limite_inferior': 22.250.00, 'limite_superior': 32.749.99, 'coeficiente': 0.15},
  {'limite_inferior': 32.750.00, 'limite_superior': 60.749.99, 'coeficiente': 0.20},
  {'limite_inferior': 60.750.00, 'limite_superior': 144.749.99, 'coeficiente': 0.25},
  {'limite_inferior': 144.750.00, 'limite_superior': None, 'coeficiente': 0.32},
]

def calculate_income_tax(self):
  # Calculate the employee's monthly gross salary.
  salary = self.employee_id.contract_id.wage

  # Calculate the income tax.
  income_tax = calcular_imposto_renda(salary, tabela_imposto)

  return income_tax
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.